# Why does this Linked List throws segmentation fault in a for loop?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in data structures and c++, I was trying to implement a linked list class with both a pointer to its first and its last node. This is the push method.

```
void push(T new_node)
{
    if (first_element == nullptr)
    {
        first_element = new Node<T>;
        first_element->val = new_node;
        last_element = first_element;
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T>* newer = new Node<T>;
        newer->val = new_node;
        last_element->next = newer; // this one
        last_element = newer;
    }
}
```

I wrote two quick tests to check if the list works, the "short" one passes perfectly, however in the "long" one I get a segmentation fault.

```
void shortTester()
{
    LinkedList<int> mylist;
    mylist.push(0);
    mylist.push(1);
    mylist.push(2);
    mylist.push(32);
    mylist.push(48);
    mylist.push(52);
    mylist.push(64);
    assert(mylist[6] == 64);
    mylist.push(99);
    assert(mylist[7] == 99);
    std::cout << "passed short test!" << std::endl;
}

void longTester()
{
    LinkedList<int> mylist;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

        mylist.push(i);
    }
    
}
```

The program throws a segmentation fault at the very first iteration of the long test, vscode marks the line I commented in the push method as the one causing it.
What could be happening? Am I using pointers and heap memory allocation incorrectly?

Comment: If your first iteration is hitting the line you marked, `first_element` probably isn't being initialized properly.

Comment: Yes that was it, thank you. I thought uninitialized pointers would default to nullptr but apparently it is not the case.

Comment: @xsjdjdnxjiwkdjsdjsuksw Definitely it is not the case. Nicely asked question BTW.

Comment: I don't share that sentiment.  Omitting relevant code such as the constructor for `Node` only leads us to speculate, rather than provide a definitive answer.  A well-formed question should include all relevant detail.